# nginx reverse proxy to a docker container from host doesn't work on certain ports

Tags: curl, nginx, proxy, docker

In my nginx.conf I have

server 
{
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

```
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;
proxy_buffering off;


location /blog/ {

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_pass http://172.17.0.94:9001/;
include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}

location /admin/ {

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_pass http://172.17.0.94:9000/;
include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}


location /api/ {

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_pass http://172.17.0.94:1337/;
include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}
```

}

The reverse proxy works and loads the admin content properly but not the /api or /blog content even though I can curl into both of them with their IP and port. Anyone more familiar with nginx that might know what's wrong here?

Comment: Try to enable access/error log and post them here

Comment: Fixed it, sorry new to Linux so the answer might be obvious to everyone but what I did in case anyone has an issue like this is checked if the port was included by, semanage port -l | grep http_port_t
And add it with this command
semanage port -a -t http_port_t  -p tcp 8090